# How do you edit a Wandering Traders' trades?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am making my own SkyBlock map and I wanted to change/add (whatever is easier) one of their trades. I want one of their trades to be a bucket of lava since this will be the only way to get the lava to then make a cobble generator. Anyone know who I can do this?

Comment: The same way as a villager probably.

Answer (score -1):

[This technique](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMk0jop73OE) would work in the same way for a Wandering Trader - just change the summon from a villager to a Wandering Trader! :)

Comment: So I would have to add every trade it currently does, then add my custom one. I would think there would be more to them though as they appear randomly and disappear again after a few in game minutes/hours.

Comment: @Steve You'd have to set a timer command that kills them and then instantly respawns them, to keep the trade exactly the same all the time (without any additions)